# I want to know how QT GUI Entry is implemented in gnuradio. I am puzzled how the code is like?

Tags: gnuradio

I find it on the website. Only the following passage:

> QTGUI Widgets
>
> The QTGUI component also includes a number of widgets that can be used to perform live updates of variables through standard QT input widgets. Most of the widgets are implemented directly in Python through PyQT. However, GNU Radio is introducing more widgets, written and therefore available in C++ that also produce messsages. The Python-based widgets only act as variables and so as they are changed, any block using those widgets to set paramters has the callback (i.e., set_value()) function's called.
>
> Entry: An edit box that allows a user to directly set a new value for the parameter.

And I only found a related file "qtgui_entry.xml" in the program.

Answer (score 1):

`qtgui_entry.xml` in fact contains the entire implementation (not counting code already in Qt, GR, and GRC). There are no other files.

If you look in it you will see code creating standard Qt widgets and setting them up.

Comment: In order for this module to support Chinese, I changed the two lines of code in the file. But there was a mistake：

Comment: @H.Dog It looks like you have a different question to do with getting GNU Radio programs working. You could [ask a new question here](/ask), but it would probably be best to take it to the GNU Radio mailing list. In any case, comments are not a good place for this.

Comment: OK，think you very much.